# Inline and inline-block work differently with vertical-align

Tags: html, css

I read this [great article](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/) on vertical-align and came up with a very confusing example:

```css
html {
  font-size: 100px;
}

body {  
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    x
    <div>      
      x
      <div>
        x
        <div>
          x
          <div>
            x
            <div>
              x
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected to see a ladder, but I did not expect that **steps of this ladder will have different heights**. Can someone explain what determines it? I noticed that when I change the display to "inline", all steps have the same height.

Comment: Interesting question, not sure why it was downvoted. A lot of crap ends up upvoted instead.

Comment: why should there be a ladder in your opinion? inline-block means blocks that are on the same line. If all of them (regardless if they are nested or not) are vertically centered, they will be at the same height. (?)

Comment: Because of how "vertical-align: middle" works (aligns midpoint of a nested inline element to a line that goes through the middle of small "x" in parent element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`vertical-align: middle`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) does exactly this:

> Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent box plus half the x-height of the parent.

[image]

<sup><sub>The red line is the baseline of the parent box plus half the x-height of the parent</sub></sup>

The different heights of the ladder are due to the fact that the midpoint of the `x` is moved closer to the midpoint of the box due to the space caused by inner nesting.

For example,

1. Suppose that the line-height is 100px, the height of the "x" is 40px, and the baseline is at 20px above the bottom. So the line has 40px empty at the top, 40px for the `x`, and 20px empty at the bottom. The middle of the "x" is at 20px + 40px/2 = 40px above the bottom, that is, 40/100 = 40%.
2. Then, you align that box to the middle, and nest it inside another box with a "x". The middle of the nested box will be aligned with the middle of the "x" of the outer box. But half height of the nested box occupies 100px/2 = 50px, while there are only 40px below the midpoint of the `x` in the outer box. Therefore, the outer box grows by 10px to prevent the nested box from overflowing.

   So the outer box will have 40px empty at the top, 40px for the outer "x", and 30px empty at the bottom (10px of which due to the alignment of the inner box). The outer box will be 110px tall. The middle of the "x" is at 30px + 40px/2 = 50px above the bottom, that is, 50/110 = 45.5%.
3. Then, you nest the previously outer box inside another box. Half height of the nested box occupies 110px/2 = 55px, while there are only 40px below the midpoint of the "x" in the outer box. Therefore, the outer box grows by 15px.

   So the outer box will have 40px empty at the top, 40px for the outer "x", and 35px empty at the bottom (15px of which due to the alignment of the inner box). The outer box will be 115px tall. The middle of the "x" is at 35px + 40px/2 = 55px above the bottom, that is, 55/115 = 47.8%.
4. Then, you nest the previously outer box inside another box. Half height of the nested box occupies 115px/2 = 57.5px, while there are only 40px below the midpoint of the "x" in the outer box. Therefore, the outer box grows by 17.5px.

   So the outer box will have 40px empty at the top, 40px for the outer "x", and 37.5px empty at the bottom (17.5px of which due to the alignment of the inner box). The outer box will be 117.5px tall. The middle of the "x" is at 37.5px + 40px/2 = 57.5px above the bottom, that is, 57.5/117.5 = 48.9%.
5. And so on. The middle of the "x" approaches the middle of its box. When that happens, the alignment will stop adding additional space.

This does not happen when you use `display: inline` because

> for inline non-replaced elements, the box used for alignment is the
>   box whose height is the `line-height` (containing the box's glyphs and
>   the half-leading on each side, see [above](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-box-height)). For all other
>   elements, the box used for alignment is the margin box.

Comment: Thanks. I think I do understand how "vertical-align: middle" works, but I don't understand why nesting inline-block elements makes their boxes smaller, and how exactly their height is calculated.

Comment: @lonelyass It's the other way round: nesting inline-blocks makes parents grow due to the extra space added when aligning.

Comment: Yeah, I got this now...

I think what makes this example so confusing is that boxes are resized right-to-left in this example, while vertical-align is applied left-to-right.

Each step of the ladder is twice smaller than previous, going right-to-left.

Comment: @lonelyass Order does not matter, left-to-right and right-to-left behave the same. I added some details.